# How can I customise error messages shown by PyInputPlus?

Tags: python, validation, input, user-input, python-phonenumber

How can I customise error messages shown by PyInputPlus in python?
I have tried many method but unable to do it.

```
import pyinputplus as pyip
number = pyip.inputNum("Enter your phone number : ",
                       min=1000000000, 
                       max=9999999999)
number
```

I want to print error message as ***please enter a valid 10 digit phone number.***
Is there any way to so it?
I try to use **"allowRegexes and blockRegexes"** but unable to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this for a real world project I would recommend using `input` from python itself, this lib doesn't seem very well documented and mantained. This could bring a lot of weird errors in your code for the future.

But to answer your question, you could do it using regex with the parameter **blockRegexes**. If you were unable to understand it, this will be more a regex question than a python question.

From [this website](https://regexr.com/) you can learn a lot about regex, that I recommend, regex is a very important tool to understand.
About your problem, [accordingly to the docs](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=blocklistRegexes#common-input-parameters):

> `blocklistRegexes` (Sequence, None): A sequence of regex str or
> `(regex_str, error_msg_str)` tuples that, if matched, will
> explicitly fail validation.

So, in your case the first item in the tuple, should be a regex to block everything that have more or less than 10 integers characters:

`^\d{10}$`

The full explanation for this regex can be found [here](http://regexr.com/6bquu)

The second item in your touple should be the string you want to appear when the error occurs:

"please enter a valid 10 digit phone number"

So your code would be like this:

```
number = pyip.inputNum("Enter your phone number : ",
                       min=1000000000, 
                       max=9999999999,
                       blockRegexes=[(r"^\d{10}$","please enter a valid 10 digit phone number")])
```

Comment: Thank you, i used input() function as u told..

Comment: @AkashKumar you could choose the answer as right if it helped you.